# How to open two documents and copy the text from one to another?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have two documents.(title.docx and style.docx). I need to replace the text(with italic format) with title.docx file text . I tried the following code. But it italicizes all the content of style.docx file instead of italicizing only specific text (from title.docx)

```
Sub OpenDoc()


Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Documents and Settings\quads\Desktop\title.docx", ConfirmConversions:=True

 Dim char As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim count As Integer


Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
x = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("NUMBER OF LINES")
For i = 0 To x
char = Selection.EndKey(Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove)
If (char > 0) Then
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, count:=i
Selection.Expand wdLine
'MsgBox (Selection.Text)
Documents.Open FileName:="C:\Documents and Settings\quads\Desktop\style.docx"
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic = True
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = _
            Selection.Text

        .Replacement.Text = _
            Selection.Text
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute


End If
ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, count:=1
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdMove
Next i
```

I need to replace the style.docx file text(with italic format) with title.docx file text.
For example:
title.docx

---

```
This is a testing text
This is a example text
This is a sample text
```

---

style.docx

---

It has some text with  the content of some other documents and also This is a testing text also would be mixed with this document.

If this line has This is a example text in this document then this also need to be italicized.

Then this is the last line of the document with This is a sample text.

---

Expected Output: style.docx

---

It has some text with  the content of some other documents and also *This is a testing text* also would be mixed with this document.

If this line has *This is a example text* in this document then this also need to be italicized.
Then this is the last line of the document with *This is a sample text*.

---

Comment: I guess you have a lot of `italic sections` in `style.docx` file, and all those sections you want to replace with what- the whole content of `title.docx` or some sections from `title.docx`. You need to explain it more detailed- how do you recognise which section from `title` match section in `style`.

Comment: I have added examples in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open new file in Word, add the following macro there and save it in the same folder where you have both `title` and `style` files. I assumed that each text you search is in separate paragraph in your `title` file. Solution works ok when I tried and tested it.

```
Sub OpenDoc()

    Dim docTitle As Document
    Dim docStyle As Document
    Set docTitle = Documents.Open(FileName:=ThisDocument.Path & "\title.docx", ConfirmConversions:=True)
    Set docStyle = Documents.Open(FileName:=ThisDocument.Path & "\style.docx", ConfirmConversions:=True)

    Dim char As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim count As Integer


    Dim Para As Paragraph

    For Each Para In docTitle.Paragraphs

        If Len(Para.Range.Text) > 1 Then


        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic = True
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = Left(Para.Range.Text, Len(Para.Range.Text) - 1)
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = True
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With
            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        End If
        ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select

    Next Para
End Sub
```

Comment: It italicizes the text in title.docx instead of style.docx.

Comment: if you follow instruction it is working correctly. I don't need to use `docStyle` any more as the macro refers to `ActiveDocument` which is ...`docStyle`. If you don't get correct result it means you didn't follow instruction and changed manually active document. If so you need to improve the code on your own to remove that kind of risk- just put `docStyle.Activate` as a first line inside the loop.

Comment: I did as you instructed but no changes in the docstyle file. only doctitle file is getting changed

Comment: so, add `docstyle.activate` as the first line in the loop as earlier suggested.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. With some changes in your code I got it worked.